# Find an algorithm to take two specific inputs and return a single specific output

Tags: algorithm

I have a data set that I would like to have a program analyse and solve for the algorithm that it uses. I only have the data and the algorithm is unknown. I have two inputs and it needs generates a single output. If possible I would like to be able to add new inputs and generate their output.

```
(Input1, Input2, Actual Output)
(542, 575, 291)
(797, 424, 202)
(529, 564, 321)
(888, 484, 523)
(789, 095, 497)
```

I have more data if necessary that I can provide. I don't really know how to start this because I cannot see a relation between the inputs and the output. It would be insanely helpful if someone could help find an algorithm to solve this so that I can plug in more data to get the correct outputs.

Edit: what is regressional analysis is and how I would use it? Also the data set is from a challenge set that I don’t now how to approach.

Comment: You are probably looking for [regression analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis)

Comment: Can you elaborate on where this data comes from? This could be a regression, as @SomeDude has noted. However, if the data here were generated by some sort of hash function, then this might be computationally infeasible.